# String Replace() / Remove() doesn't work

Tags: powershell

I want to remove a part of a string for search and group, otherwise it can't search it, but `Replace()`/`Remove()` are not working:

```cs
    $RootPath = $Selection
    $Folders = dir $RootPath | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}
    try {
        foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
            $ACLs = Get-Acl $Folder.FullName | ForEach-Object {
                $_.Access
            }
            foreach ($ACL in $ACLs) {
                if ($ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "Administrators" -and $ACL.IdentityReference - notlike "Creator Owner" - and $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "BUILTIN\Administrators" -and $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -and $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "System") {
                    $strAcl = $ACL.IdentityReference
                    # value is for instance GESCOEUROPE\GR_G-FCASB-INT-ALL
                }
            }
        }

        $strNames = $strAcl.Replace("GESCOEUROPE\", "")
        # or:
        #$strNames = $strAcl.Remove(0, 12)

        $strUsers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $strNames -Recursive |
                    Get-ADUser -Property DisplayName |
                    Select Name |
                    Sort-Object Name
        $OutInfo = $Folder.FullName + "," + $trAcl + $strUsers
        $OutInfo | Select-Object -Unique
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile | Sort-Object -Unique
    } catch [System.IO.IOException] {
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside: your code loops over multiple folders, and over each of their ACLs, but only ever saves a _single_ value in `$strAcl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `$strAcl` to `$ACL.IdentityReference`, which is of type `[System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]` (verify with [`Get-Member`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member)); it is *not* a *string*, so you cannot call `.Replace()` on it.

If you want to stringify `$ACL.IdentityReference`, call `.ToString()` on it, or cast it to `[string]`, or enclose it in an expression inside a double-quoted string:

```
# Call .ToString()
$strAcl = $ACL.IdentityReference.ToString()

# Cast to [string]
$strAcl = [string] $ACL.IdentityReference

# Use string interpolation:
$strAcl = "$($ACL.IdentityReference)"
```

Note: In *this* case, all 3 methods are equivalent, but there are cases where `.ToString()` is *culture-sensitive*<sup>[1]</sup>
, whereas the other 2 methods are always culture-*in*sensitive.

---

<sup>[1] Try `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = 'de-DE'; (0.5).ToString(); [string] 0.5; "$(0.5)"`</sup>